# Issue with Session state in MVC3 ASP.NET Working locally but not when published to IIS8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have an application which performs a search on a database and enables the user to update certain fields. When the user returns from the edit view back to the search view I want to display the original search results. I have used session to store two strings which are passed to my Search action to filter the search. When I'm running my application locally everything works as it should but after i publish the application to IIS8 the session state seems to be cleared after I save the changes to the database and navigate back to the search.

Here are the ActionResults in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString, string SearchOption) 
    {
        Session["searchString"] = searchString;
        Session["SearchOption"] = SearchOption;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            searchString = searchString.Replace(" ", "");
            if (SearchOption == "PolicyNumber")
            {
                var vehicles = from v in db.Vehicles
                               where v.VehiclePolicyNumber == searchString
                               orderby v.VehiclePolicyNumber, v.DateVehicleAddedPolicy
                               select v;                    
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View(vehicles);
            }
            else
            {
                //Search for vehicle policy numbers
                var vehiclePolicies = from v in db.Vehicles
                               where v.RegistrationNumber == searchString
                               select v.VehiclePolicyNumber;

                //Search for vehicles with the above policy numbers
                var vehicles = from v in db.Vehicles
                                      where vehiclePolicies.Contains(v.VehiclePolicyNumber)
                                      orderby v.VehiclePolicyNumber, v.DateVehicleAddedPolicy
                                      select v;                    
                ModelState.Clear();
                return View(vehicles);
            }
        }
        else 
        {                
            var vehicles1 = from v in db.Vehicles
                            where v.VehicleMake == "g"
                            select v;
            return View(vehicles1);                
        }          
    }        

    public ActionResult editOnDate(string id)
    {
        var onDateToEdit = (from Vehicle in db.Vehicles where Vehicle.VehicleId.Equals(id) select Vehicle).First();            
        return View(onDateToEdit);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult editOnDate(string id, Vehicle vehicle) 
    {
        var onDateToEdit = (from Vehicle in db.Vehicles where Vehicle.VehicleId.Equals(id) select Vehicle).First();
        onDateToEdit.VehicleOnDate = vehicle.VehicleOnDate;
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.Message = "Saved!";
        return View(onDateToEdit);
    }
```

The session data should be passed to the Search view using this action link:

```
 <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to Search", "Search", "Vehicle", new {searchString = Session["searchString"], SearchOption = Session["SearchOption"]}, new { @class = "barButton" })%>
```

Everything works locally but its frustrating that it doesn't work when published. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where are you storing session on the local machine and the II8 machine? You'll find the setting in <sessionState> in the web.config at the root of your project. I suspect the II8 install isn't configured properly.

Comment: <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" /> Is that what you're after? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Is that the IIS8 machine or local? It it's IIS8 is it a load balanced environment? That means there's two or more web servers running the application together. (And don't apologize for being new :D)

Comment: Thanks Phil :D. I'm not too sure, that's the only tag for session state in the web.config so its probably for local. I'm finding out about the load state environment now.

Comment: See if you can find the web.config for the server as well. I'd imagine it's session state tag will reveal more.

Comment: Its not load balanced, there is only one copy

Comment: Copy your session state tag from the local machine into the web.config on the IIS8 machine. And see if that works.

Comment: I've tried that now but it still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Is IIS configured for asp.net session state?

Comment: Yeh it is configured, ive just had a look at the session state settings in the iis manager. In proc is selected and cookie settings is set to use cookies.

Comment: Can you cut and past the sessionstate tag from the IIS8 machine?

Comment: There only seems to be one web config file on the iis8 machine and it contains <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" /> the same as the local one.